# Is it possible to change image of extension to UIImageView from project?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-keyboard-extension

I have two targets in project, first one (shop) is some kind of a shop for backgrounds, the second target is extension (keyboard).

So, in shop I have Collection View and in didSelectItemAt I want to call method to the extension target (keyboard).

```
// file: ShopController.swift
let kbvc = KeyboardViewController()

// ...

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  kbvc.setBGrImage(data[indexPath.item])
}




// file: KeyboardViewController.swift
lazy var bgrImageView: UIImageView = {
  let i = UIImageView()
  i.image = UIImage(named: "Bgr1")
  return i
}()

// in viewDidLoad add to the view, put constraints etc...
func setBGrImage(_ image: String) {
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.bgrImageView.image = UIImage(named: image)
     self.bgrImageView.setNeedsDisplay()
   }
   // Breakpoint / print shows that image is here...
   /*
    po bgrImageView.image
    Optional<UIImage>
      - some : <UIImage:0x600003197450 named(main: Bgr2) {320, 225}> 
   */
}
```

...but ImageView not change image.

Is it even possible to do it like this or need something else?

Thanks

Comment: did you try specifying or changing the target for the particular swift file that contains the extension?

Comment: If you think of Target Membership for the file then yes...